# Checking if two IDs of two elements with the same class are equal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My **HTML** looks like this:

```
<h1 id="dictionaryTitle">Intrebari frecvente</h1>
<p class="question" id="q1">QUESTION1</p>
<p class="answer" id="q1">ANSWER1</p>
<p class="question" id="q2">QUESTION2</p>
<p class="answer" id="q2">ANSWER2</p>
```

The **JavaScript/jQuery** looks like this:

```
$('.question').on("click",function() {
    if ($('.answer').css('display') === 'none') {
        $('.answer').css({'display': 'block',});
    } else {
        $('.answer').css({'display': 'none',});
    }
});
```

The question is how can I check if the IDs are equal so that I can only change the display of only one of the answer and not all of them?

Comment: Are you trying to fix the duplicate IDs or it's an intentional feature?

Comment: ids are unique !

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. ID's are supposed to be unique. As such there is no reason to try to do what you want to do.

Comment: You should change your concept here as it is (strictly speaking) not correct to have more than one element with the same id attribute

Comment: than what measure should I use to only change the display of the respective answer when one question in clicked? thanks

Comment: Not saying IDs are ideal, but you at the very least use `q1`/`a1` convention as opposed to `q1`/`q1`

Comment: @M.Vlad Use classes instead. class="question q1" class="answer q1"

Comment: use can use data attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told you gforce301, the ID must be unique, anyway you can use this solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.question').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).next('.answer').css('display') === 'none') {
      $(this).next('.answer').css({ 'display': 'block' });
    } else {
      $(this).next('.answer').css({ 'display': 'none' });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="dictionaryTitle">Intrebari frecvente</h1>

<p class="question" id="q1">QUESTION1</p>
<p class="answer" id="q1">ANSWER1</p>

<p class="question" id="q2">QUESTION2</p>
<p class="answer" id="q2">ANSWER2</p>
```

Comment: You're welcome, check it as the correct answer if you think :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to be keying this off of `id`, as they need to be unique. Instead, create an attribute for this purpose, then you can check those.

### HTML

```
<h1 id="dictionaryTitle">Intrebari frecvente</h1>
<p class="question" data-question="q1">QUESTION1</p>
<p class="answer" data-question="q1">ANSWER1</p>
<p class="question" data-question="q2">QUESTION2</p>
<p class="answer" data-question="q2">ANSWER2</p>
```

### jQuery

```
$('.question').on("click", function() {
    $('.answer').css({'display': 'none',})
    $('.answer[data-question="' + $(this.attr('data-question') + '"]')).css({'display': 'block',});
});
```

So what we are doing here is when you click on a question, hide all answers, then show the answer where the `data-question` attribute matches the `data-question` attribute of the question.

Answer (score 0):

IDs should be unique in html
anyway you can make it work using the following workaround

```
$('.question').on("click",function() {
    $id = "#"+$(this).attr('id');
if ($($id+'.answer').css('display') === 'none') {

        $($id+'.answer').css({'display': 'block',});
        }
        else {
            $($id+'.answer').css({'display': 'none',});
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the "answers" inside the "questions", so you could show/hide those using:

```
$(this).find(".answer")
```

See following example please:

```js
$('.question').on("click",function() {
    if ($(this).find('.answer').css('display') === 'none') {
        $(this).find('.answer').css({'display': 'block',});
    } else {
        $(this).find('.answer').css({'display': 'none',});
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="dictionaryTitle">Intrebari frecvente</h1>
<div class="question" id="q1">QUESTION1
  <p class="answer" id="q1">ANSWER1</p>
</div>
<div class="question" id="q2">QUESTION2
  <p class="answer" id="q2">ANSWER2</p>
</div>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the answer immediately after the question. You can also hide all of the answers before showing one using [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

```
$('.question').on("click",function() {
    $(".answer").hide();
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1zmrf9s/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As said, the proper way to code is by using unique ID. A good way to do that is to use div in order to properly separate the questions and answers.

Here's a fiddle to show you a good way to do so. ( keep in mind that that is not the best way, just a better way ( and working one ) to do )

### HTML

```
<h1 id="dictionaryTitle">Intrebari frecvente</h1>

<div id="q1">
  <p class="question">QUESTION1</p>
  <p class="answer" hidden>ANSWER1</p>
</div>

<div id="q2">
  <p class="question">QUESTION2</p>
  <p class="answer" hidden>ANSWER2</p>
</div>
```

### JQUERY

```
$(function() {

  $('p').click(function(){
        $(this).next('p').show();
  });

});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kkf4uLq1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute value must be unique. To avoid this issue, you can wrap your question and answer in a div that has the id q1, q2, etc...

Here's a snippet :

```js
$('div .question').on("click",function() {
    var $answer = $(this).next('.answer');
    
    if ($answer.css('display') === 'none') {
        $answer.css({'display': 'block',});
    } else {
        $answer.css({'display': 'none',});
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="dictionaryTitle">Intrebari frecvente</h1>
<div id="q1">
  <p class="question">QUESTION1</p>
  <p class="answer">ANSWER1</p>
</div>

<div id="q2">
  <p class="question">QUESTION2</p>
  <p class="answer">ANSWER2</p>
</div>
```